# Handling container stop/reload event

Tags: scala, lift, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

A have lift app starting ssh daemon in Boot.scala.
Here is the problem: when i run `container:restart /` in sbt session I get *Address alread in use* exception.
Now two questions:

1. Is it right way to start dependent service in Boot.scala?
2. Anyway how is it possible to handle container:stop event?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the Lift-y way to do it is with [`LiftRules.unloadHooks`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.http.LiftRules).

It's not well-documented (AFAIK), but if you look in the Lift source code, you'll see that when the [`LiftServlet`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.http.LiftServlet) is `destroy()`ed, the functions defined in `LiftRules.unloadHooks` are executed.

You can add functions to the `unloadHooks` [`RulesSeq`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.http.LiftRules$RulesSeq) with the `append` or `prepend` method, depending on what order you want them executed in. So, in your `bootstrap.liftweb.Boot.boot` method, you might do something like this:

```
sshDaemon.start()
LiftRules.unloadHooks.append( () => sshDaemon.stop() )
```

(Assuming that was how you started and stopped your SSH daemon.)

I'm not 100% certain the `LiftServlet.destroy()` method gets invoked when the sbt web-plugin's `container:restart` command is run - that's determined by the plugin and its interaction with Jetty, not by Lift - but the `container:stop` command should definitely do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

*I'm not familiar with Lift, but this advice should work for any Servlet based web application.*

Register a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) in your `web.xml`, and release any resources in the `contextDestroyed` method. (The startup should be done in the `contextCreated` method.)

You can use `setAttribute` / `getAttribute` to store and later retrieve the server.

Putting this all together:

```
import javax.servlet.{ServletContextEvent, ServletContextListener}


final class SshListener extends ServletContextListener{
  val attributeKey = "sshServer"

  def contextInitialized(sce: ServletContextEvent) {
    val server = new Server()
    server.start()
    sce.getServletContext.setAttribute(attributeKey, server)
  }

  def contextDestroyed(sce: ServletContextEvent) {
    Option(sce.getServletContext.getAttribute(attributeKey)).foreach(_.asInstanceOf[Server].stop())
  }
}

class Server {
  def start()
  def stop()
}
```